# How to use requests library to webscrape a list of links already scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped a set of links off a website (https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk) - all the links including the words meetings, i.e. the meeting papers, which are now contained in 'meeting_links'. I now need to follow each of them links to scrape some more links within them.

I've gone back to using the request library and tried

```
r2 = requests.get("meeting_links")
```

But it returns the following error:

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'list_meeting_links': No schema supplied. 
Perhaps you meant http://list_meeting_links?
```

Which I've changed it to but still no difference.

This is my code so far and how I got the links from the first url that I wanted.

```
# importing libaries and defining
import requests
import urllib.request
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# set url
url = "https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk/" 

# grab html 
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'lxml')

# creating folder to store pfds - if not create seperate folder
folder_location = r'E:\Internship\WORK'

# getting all meeting href off url
meeting_links = soup.find_all('a',href='TRUE')
for link in meeting_links:
    print(link['href'])
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        print("Meeting!") 

#second set of links
r2 = requests.get("meeting_links")
```

Do I need to do something with the 'meeting_links' before I can start using the requests library again? I'm completely lost.

Comment: You need to supply a valid URL to `requests.get()`. Now you just printing `Meeting!` on the screen. Instead of printing `Meeting!`, you can store the URL or do another request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your new requests could be here:

```
for link in meeting_links:
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        r2 = requests.get(link['href']) 

        <Do something with the request>
```

Because it looks like you are trying to pass a string to the requests method.
Request method should look like this:

```
requests.get('https://example.com')
```